# CAN ports on STM32F407G board

Tags: can, stm32f4

The project I'm starting with requires multiple development-boards connected with CAN buses.

Is it possible to put two CAN ports on an STM32F407G board?

Comment: According to RTFM there appears to be two CAN peripherals on the MCU. However, it doesn't look like the board has any CAN transceivers so you have to add those externally. Quite messy - you can do that for test/hobbyist purposes only.

Comment: Can you qualify what you mean by "putting CAN ports __on__ board"? The MCU already has 2 CAN ports, you don't need to put anything there. But as @Lundin mentioned above, you do need transceivers, and you cannot put them __on__ board because Discovery boards do not have place for them. Or do you mean custom board with STM32F407*G controller?

Answer (score 1):

You CAN use two buses (you'll need a transceiver for each, though), but do you need to do this? You can connect all devices into one network and use packet filtering provided by CAN peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a lot of STM32s have multiple CAN ports, and you can check by downloading a tool, STM Cube (see [link](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html)).

A ...G does not exist, but VG does. See here more information:

[Info](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32-high-performance-mcus/stm32f4-series/stm32f407-417/stm32f407vg.html)

It shows:

◾2 × CAN interfaces (2.0B Active)

This [table](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f4-series.html?querycriteria=productId=SS1577) shows which other STM32s have two CAN buses.